# How to represent isobaric processes using the equation for the first law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, volume

According to Kaplan physics book, there are “multiple possible forms” for FLoT equation with isobaric processes but that doesn’t make sense to me. I know that the FLoT equation is

$$\Delta U = Q - W$$

I also know that in isobaric processes $W = P\Delta V$. So I’d assume that for any question involving isobaric processes, some combination of $P$, $V_f$, $V_i$, $Q$, and $\Delta U$ would be given and I would have to just use these two equations to find the desired variable. I’m not sure what other forms there would be

Comment: What is FLoT supposed to be?

Comment: Same question as Chet Miller

Comment: OK.  First Law of Thermodynamics = FLoT.  Can you please provide more of the quote from Kaplan.  We need more context.

Comment: Exactly what is it you are trying to do? Determine the work done?

Comment: There is no world problem or anything like that. I just had a table that said “special types of thermodynamic processes”. One column lists the processes and the other said “ first law of thermodynamics reduces to...”. In the part that says isobaric it said “multiple possible forms”. It also had the equations for the other processes. Isothermal —> Q = W, adiabatic —> delta U = -W, and isovolumetric —> delta U = Q. Also yes, FLoT is the abbreviation for first law of thermodynamics

Comment: If it helps use this link: https://schoolbag(dot)info/physics/physics_math/17.html and read the part labeled “thermodynamic processes”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what your goal is, but if it is to determine the work done for an isobaric process, then obviously if you know $\Delta U$ and $Q$ you can calculate $W$.

In order to calculate the work directly from $W=P\Delta V$, the constant pressure $P$ is always the external pressure, and of course $\Delta V=V_{f}-V_{i}$.

If the isobaric process is reversible, then the gas is in internal equilibrium and its pressure throughout will always gas equal the external pressure. For a reversible process involving an ideal gas, the ideal gas law applies at every point in the process. For an irreversible process, the ideal gas law only applies to the initial and final equilibrium states.

Beyond that, without seeing Kaplan's statement "there are 'multiple possible forms' for FLoT equation with isobaric processes" in context, it's not clear what this means. For example, for an ideal gas reversible isobaric process one can substitute $mC_{v}\Delta T$ for $\Delta U$ and substitute $mC_{p}\Delta T$ for $Q$ and thereby change the form of the first law to:

$$mC_{v}\Delta T=mC_{p}\Delta T-P\Delta V$$

For what it's worth, hope this helps.

Comment: This sounds like it answered my question and I really appreciate your answer because it answered some questions I didn’t know I had and I think it applies to this. I provided a link in the comments above which provides all the context I can think of

Comment: @Ibby Well if you think it answered your question, and no other answers have been given, then why didn't you accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry I forget to do that cuz I’m new to this. I just did that

Comment: @Ibby No problem. Common for new contributors. Thanks for the recognition.